# gdb core dump "is not a core dump: File format not recognized"

Tags: c, gdb

I compiled my C file `test` with the flags `-g -Wall -std=gnu99 -pedantic`

I ran it and a `core` file was created

I tried analysing it `gdb test core` and I get this error message

```
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from test...done.
"/[...]/aula02/core" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
```

Comment: Do you have a limitation on the core size? (check with `ulimit -c`)

Comment: yes, I've changed it already, before that the file didn't appear at all

Comment: @94230 Is the core file the same size as the limit you set?  If so, you're discovering that an incomplete core file is effectively useless.  The only core file limit setting that guarantees a useful core file is `unlimited`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, the file is blank, not a single byte

Comment: @AndrewHenle A truncated core is not entirely useless. I have dealt with a few cores truncated at 3MB and invariably my GDB managed to read out thread lists, register sets, a backtrace and `info proc mappings`, without however being able to read memory. However, the `$pc` would often be enough, in conjunction with the process memory map snd a few registers, to identify what caused a crash.

Comment: @94230 Are you using virtual box? what is the underlying file system of current directory?

Comment: @ThePhilomath Thanks, that was it, I was using a VM and running files on a macOS directory, I copied everything to the linux desktop and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a VirtualMachine and executing files that were on a macOS directory, when doing it in the VM Desktop it works fine